# Examples of adaibatic and isothermal process from daily life

Tags: thermodynamics, forces, energy, mass, solid-state-physics

i am not actually understanding the applications of isothermal and adaibatic process in daily life. could any one help me with best examples , that would help me to catch up with the topic

Comment: "Adiabatic compressions actually occur in the cylinders of a car, where the compressions of the gas-air mixture take place so quickly that there is no time for the mixture to exchange heat with its environment. " https://phys.libretexts.org/TextMaps/University_Physics_TextMaps/Map%3A_University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Map%3A_University_Physics_II_-_Thermodynamics%2C_Electricity%2C_and_Magnetism_(OpenStax)/3%3A_The_First_Law_of_Thermodynamics/3.6%3A_Adiabatic_Processes_for_an_Ideal_Gas

Answer (score 1):

Why does it snow over mountains? Not just because they are high.  There is air of the same altitude covering the entire planet.

It snows because air cools (adiabatically) when it ascends the mountain. The cooling of a compressed air can when discharged, and the formation of clouds above mountains, at weather fronts, and by convection are examples with the same underlying process.  A packet of higher pressure air pushes against a region of lower pressure air, either outside the nozzle of the can, or outside a column of air through which an ascending packet of high pressure air expands into. The expending air does work on the lower pressure air, pushing it outwards (and ultimately to lift the atmosphere).  This work is done without heat transfer, so the higher pressure air cools without (much) warming of the surrounding air.